# Python XlsxWriter defining X Axis on a line graph not working

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Hey guys so I'm trying to define the categorical axis as a set of dates listed in excel under the format "01 April 2020". I defined the range under categories like I'm supposed to, but I don't get an error and nothing happens. Any ideas? Please don't link this question to the other question about defining the categorical, as I did the exact thing it said and it did not work :/.

```
Report_Chart = workbook.add_chartsheet('Report Numbers')  
chart = workbook.add_chart({'type' : 'line'})

chart.add_series({'name': 'Report Source 1',
'categories' : '=Daily Report!$B$1:$W$1',
'values': '=Daily Report!$B$2:$W$2'})

chart.add_series({'name': 'Report Source 2',
'categories' : '=Daily Report!$B$1:$W$1',
'values': '=Daily Report!$B$3:$W$3'})
Report_Chart.set_chart(chart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel requires that you single quote sheet names that contain spaces. The following should work:

```
chart.add_series({'name': 'Report Source 1',
                  'categories' : "='Daily Report'!$B$1:$W$1",
                  'values': "='Daily Report'!$B$2:$W$2"})
```

Or you can let XlsxWriter deal with the quoting issues for you by using the programmatic/list version of `add_series()`:

```
chart.add_series({'name': 'Report Source 1',
                  'categories' : ['Daily Report', 0, 1, 0, 22],
                  'values':      ['Daily Report', 1, 1, 1, 22]})
```